# Парсинг обьекта Jquery из JSON

Tags: html, jquery, json, веб-программирование, localstorage

Я сохраняю джквери объект который содержит в себе кучу других элементов, в JSON, что-бы хранить его в локальном хранилище, и при загрузке(обновлении) страницы вытягиваю его и заменяю старым. 
Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как адекватно привести возращаемый object из метода parse() к джквери объекту

```
let data = $('.main_content')
alert(data.html()) //тут выводит например хтмл содержимое, все хорошо
data = JSON.stringify(data)
alert(data)
// распарсиваем обратно
data = JSON.parse(data) 
//Тут уже не выходит вызвать метод, т.к. это уже не является объектом джквери
alert(data.html())
```

Как исправить эту проблему, или какое альтернативное решение есть для этого?
P.s. хранить просто хтмл не выходит, т.к. во время жизни страницы, туда динамически добавляются обаботчики, данные и.т.д. которые не сохраняются в хтмл возращаемый методом html()

Comment: "туда динамически добавляются обаботчики" - как Вы себе представляете сохранение этой информации в виде строки? То, что Вы хотите сделать, не сработает.

Comment: @Igor я знаю что не работает, поэтому и хочу сохранить объект и его состояние, а не разметку в которой как раз и не хранится данная информация. По крайней мере любую информацию можно представить строкой, вопрос в том, каким образом, что мне и нужно знать

Comment: "По крайней мере любую информацию можно представить строкой" - это Вы как решили?

Comment: Вам придется писать код, сохраняющий и восстанавливающий *данные*, потому что *поведение* в `localStorage` сохранить не удастся.

Answer (score 0):

как-то так:

```
alert($(data).html());
```

Comment: Нет, возвращаемый объект не приводится к джквери объекту